# How to improve TikZ diagram with a lot of edges?

Tags: tikz-pgf, edge

I have a diagram with 5 nodes and edges to each other, which leads to clumpy corners:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}
\tikzset{subjekt/.style={rectangle,draw,minimum height=.7cm, minimum width=2.5cm, align=center},
         strom/.style={line width=3pt, shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt},
         gueterstrom/.style={strom,Goldenrod,->},
         geldstrom/.style={strom,SlateGrey,->}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5cm]
    \node[subjekt] (H) at (0,0) {Haushalt};
    \node[subjekt] (U) [below right= of H] {Unternehmen};
    \node[subjekt] (S) [above right= of U] {Staat};
    \node[subjekt] (B) [below left= of U]  {Banken};
    \node[subjekt] (A) [below right= of U] {Ausland};
    \draw (H) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[left] {3} (B);
    \draw (B) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[right] {9} (H);
    \draw (H) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[below] {1} (S);
    \draw (S) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[above] {13} (H);
    \draw (H) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[below left] {2} (U);
    \draw (U) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[above right] {6} (H);
    \draw (H) edge[bend right=22,geldstrom, near end] node[below left] {4} (A);
    \draw (A) edge[bend right=22,geldstrom, near end] node[above right] {20} (H);
    \draw (B) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[below right] {10} (U);
    \draw (U) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[above left] {7} (B);
    \draw (B) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[below] {12} (A);
    \draw (A) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[above] {19} (B);
    \draw (B) edge[bend right=22,geldstrom, near end] node[below right] {11} (S);
    \draw (S) edge[bend right=22,geldstrom, near end] node[above left] {16} (B);
    \draw (A) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[above right] {18} (U);
    \draw (U) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[below left] {8} (A);
    \draw (A) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[right] {17} (S);
    \draw (S) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[left] {14} (A);
    \draw (S) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[above left] {15} (U);
    \draw (U) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[below right] {5} (S);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Any idea how to improve the situation in the corners?

Comment: Just a thought: instead of two arrows going back and forth just one with two heads.

Comment: Change `rectangle` to `circle`?

Comment: @marmot That's not possible, there are two different money streams -> numbers for explanation

Comment: You could still place the streams (numbers) above and below (or left and right) of the arrow and indicate the directions by small arrows.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

like this?

[image]

### **edit**

in comparison to your code the code in mwe, by which  the above image was drawm, has the following changes/improvements:

- by introducing library `quotes` writing of edge labels is simplified and much  shorter. for example, instead of

`\draw (H) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[left] {3} (B);`

is possible obtain the same result with

`\draw   (H) edge ["3"]  (B)`

where for edge i define style, which determine edge *color*, *thickness*, *shortness*  and *bending angle*:

```
every edge/.style = {draw=SlateGrey, -Stealth, line width=2pt,
                     shorten <=5pt, shorten > = 5pt,
                     bend right=8},
```

- the angle of bending is essentially determined by trial and error method. however there i exploit my experiences from drawing of the similar diagrams and knowledge of geometry (already my first trial was successful). in the edge style i determine the most common angle, exceptions for four edges are determined locally.
- since edges style is defined, there is no more need to write `\draw ... :` for each edge. it is sufficient write it ones and then list all edges (see mwe below).
- with style `edge quotes` is determined font size and position of edge labels.
- size of nodes shapes is also changed. used bigger height (and also with shortening of edges) prevent edges overlaps.
- with library `arrows.meta` is defined on decent ways arrows heads
- summary of `tikzpicture` changes are:

  - style `subjekt` is renewed
  - styles `strom`, `gueterstrom` and `geldstrom` are replaced by `every edge` and `every edge quotes`

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[auto=right,
    node distance = 44mm,
   subjekt/.style = {draw, semithick, minimum height=12mm, minimum width=24mm},
every edge/.style = {draw=SlateGrey, -Stealth, line width=2pt,
                     shorten <=5pt, shorten > = 5pt,
                     bend right=8},
every edge quotes/.append style = {inner sep=2pt, font=\small, pos=0.6},
                    ]
\node (H) [subjekt]                     {Haushalt};
\node (U) [subjekt,below right=of H]    {Unternehmen};
\node (S) [subjekt,above right=of U]    {Staat};
\node (B) [subjekt,below left =of U]    {Banken};
\node (A) [subjekt,below right=of U]    {Ausland};
%
\draw   (H) edge ["3"]  (B)
        (B) edge ["9"]  (H)
        (H) edge ["1"]  (S)
        (S) edge ["13"] (H)
        (H) edge ["2"]  (U)
        (U) edge ["6"]  (H)
%
        (H) edge [bend right=24, "4"]  (A)
        (A) edge [bend right=24, "20"] (H)
%
        (B) edge ["10"] (U)
        (U) edge ["7"]  (B)
        (B) edge ["12"] (A)
        (A) edge ["19"] (B)
%
        (B) edge [bend right=24, "11"] (S)
        (S) edge [bend right=24, "16"] (B)
%
        (A) edge ["18"] (U)
        (U) edge ["8"]  (A)
        (A) edge ["17"] (S)
        (S) edge ["14"] (A)
        (S) edge ["15"] (U)
        (U) edge ["5"]  (S);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The best answer! But adding some details instead of „like this“ would probably help. For the bend right values: trial and error to choose them?

Comment: @Patwie, i will ad some explanation [regardless that the code is self explanatory to me :-) ]  asap. for bending angle i essential use trial and error method, however my experiences from drawings and use of geometry help me that was my first trial successful :-)

Comment: @Patwie, see added explanations in edit of answer. is now better?

Comment: @Zarko: I don't see any edits...

Comment: oh, i forgot upload them :-(. now are presented :-)

Comment: I already upvoted this answer due to its elegance before. But the edits might help others reading this answer.

Answer (score 18):

The arrangement you chose is very suboptimal for a fully connected graph.  It is better to arrange things in a circular layout.

TikZ `graphdrawing` requires LuaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,quotes}
\usegdlibrary{circular}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[
  simple necklace layout,
  edges={bend right=10},
  edge quotes={fill=white,inner sep=1pt,font=\tiny},
  nodes={draw},
  node sep=5em,
  ] {
    Haushalt -> {Staat [>"1"], Unternehmen [>"2"], Banken [>"3"], Ausland [>"4"]},
    Unternehmen -> {Haushalt [>"6"], Staat [>"5"], Banken [>"7"], Ausland [>"8"]},
    Banken -> {Haushalt [>"9"], Staat [>"11"], Unternehmen [>"10"], Ausland [>"12"]},
    Staat -> {Haushalt [>"13"], Unternehmen [>"15"], Banken [>"16"], Ausland [>"14"]},
    Ausland -> {Haushalt [>"20"], Staat [>"17"], Unternehmen [>"18"], Banken [>"19"]}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

How to improve the situation in the corners? Get rid of the corners! I also changed the arrow tips and tightened things up a bit.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}
\tikzset{subjekt/.style={circle,draw,minimum height=.7cm, minimum width=2.2cm, align=center},
         strom/.style={line width=2pt, shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt},
         gueterstrom/.style={strom,Goldenrod,->},
         geldstrom/.style={strom,SlateGrey,->}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm,>=stealth]
    \node[subjekt] (H) at (0,0) {Haushalt};
    \node[subjekt] (U) [below right= of H] {Unternehmen};
    \node[subjekt] (S) [above right= of U] {Staat};
    \node[subjekt] (B) [below left= of U]  {Banken};
    \node[subjekt] (A) [below right= of U] {Ausland};
    \draw (H) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[left] {3} (B);
    \draw (B) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[right] {9} (H);
    \draw (H) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[below] {1} (S);
    \draw (S) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[above] {13} (H);
    \draw (H) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[below left] {2} (U);
    \draw (U) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[above right] {6} (H);
    \draw (H) edge[bend right=22,geldstrom, near end] node[below left] {4} (A);
    \draw (A) edge[bend right=22,geldstrom, near end] node[above right] {20} (H);
    \draw (B) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[below right] {10} (U);
    \draw (U) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[above left] {7} (B);
    \draw (B) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[below] {12} (A);
    \draw (A) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[above] {19} (B);
    \draw (B) edge[bend right=22,geldstrom, near end] node[below right] {11} (S);
    \draw (S) edge[bend right=22,geldstrom, near end] node[above left] {16} (B);
    \draw (A) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[above right] {18} (U);
    \draw (U) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[below left] {8} (A);
    \draw (A) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[right] {17} (S);
    \draw (S) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[left] {14} (A);
    \draw (S) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[above left] {15} (U);
    \draw (U) edge[bend right=10,geldstrom] node[below right] {5} (S);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks much better indeed. Unfortunately, the rectangles have an implicit meaning in a series of diagrams.

Comment: @Josef I see. I guess if such a trivial solution would work you wouldn't have posted the question.

Answer (score 13):

I really find the large number of lines a bit confusing, here is a proposal to reduce it.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,shapes,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{subjekt/.style={rectangle,draw,minimum height=.7cm, minimum width=2.5cm, align=center},
         strom/.style={line width=3pt, shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt},
         gueterstrom/.style={strom,Goldenrod,->},
         geldstrom/.style={strom,SlateGrey,-,
         postaction={decoration={markings,
            mark=at position 0.7 with {\arrow[shorten >=0pt,shorten <=0pt,->]
            {>}}},decorate}},
         bendstrom/.style={strom,SlateGrey,-,
         postaction={decoration={markings,
            mark=at position 0.8 with {\arrow[shorten >=0pt,shorten <=0pt,->]
            {>}}},decorate}}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5cm,>=Stealth]
    \node[subjekt] (H) at (0,0) {Haushalt};
    \node[subjekt] (U) [below right= of H] {Unternehmen};
    \node[subjekt] (S) [above right= of U] {Staat};
    \node[subjekt] (B) [below left= of U]  {Banken};
    \node[subjekt] (A) [below right= of U] {Ausland};
    \begin{scope}[inner sep=6pt,pos=0.68]
    \draw (H) edge[geldstrom] node[left] {3} (B);
    \draw (B) edge[geldstrom] node[left] {9} (H);
    \draw (H) edge[geldstrom] node[above] {1} (S);
    \draw (S) edge[geldstrom] node[above] {13} (H);
    \draw (H) edge[geldstrom] node[above right] {2} (U);
    \draw (U) edge[geldstrom] node[above right] {6} (H);
    \draw (B) edge[geldstrom] node[below right] {10} (U);
    \draw (U) edge[geldstrom] node[below right] {7} (B);
    \draw (B) edge[geldstrom] node[below] {12} (A);
    \draw (A) edge[geldstrom] node[below] {19} (B);
    \draw (A) edge[geldstrom] node[above right] {18} (U);
    \draw (U) edge[geldstrom] node[above right] {8} (A);
    \draw (A) edge[geldstrom] node[right] {17} (S);
    \draw (S) edge[geldstrom] node[right] {14} (A);
    \draw (S) edge[geldstrom] node[below right] {15} (U);
    \draw (U) edge[geldstrom] node[below right] {5} (S);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[inner sep=6pt,pos=0.78]
    \draw (H) edge[bend right=22,bendstrom] node[below left] {4} (A);
    \draw (A) edge[bend left=22,bendstrom] node[below left] {20} (H);
    \draw (B) edge[bend left=22,bendstrom] node[above left] {11} (S);
    \draw (S) edge[bend right=22,bendstrom] node[above left] {16} (B);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Simplified the code, moved the annotations in such a way that the graph becomes less busy, and stole the arrows from @Zarko's answer.

Comment: Original, bravo !

Answer (score 5):

Base on @marmot's idea, to avoid maximum crossings :

[image]

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,shapes,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{subjekt/.style={rectangle,draw,minimum height=.7cm, minimum width=2.5cm, align=center},
         strom/.style={line width=3pt, shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt},
         gueterstrom/.style={strom,Goldenrod,->},
         geldstrom/.style={strom,SlateGrey,-,
         postaction={decoration={markings,
            mark=at position 0.7 with {\arrow[shorten >=0pt,shorten <=0pt,->]
            {>}}},decorate}},
         bendstrom/.style={strom,SlateGrey,-,
         postaction={decoration={markings,
            mark=at position 0.72 with {\arrow[shorten >=0pt,shorten <=0pt,->]
            {>}}},decorate}}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5cm,>=Stealth]
    \node[subjekt] (H) at (-1.5,3.5) {Haushalt};
    \node[subjekt] (U) at (2,0) {Unternehmen};
    \node[subjekt] (S) at (5,5) {Staat};
    \node[subjekt] (B) at (-1.5,-3.5)  {Banken};
    \node[subjekt] (A) at (5,-5) {Ausland};
    \begin{scope}[inner sep=6pt,pos=0.68]
    \draw (H) edge[geldstrom] node[left] {3} (B);
    \draw (B) edge[geldstrom] node[left] {9} (H);
    \draw (H) edge[geldstrom] node[above] {1} (S);
    \draw (S) edge[geldstrom] node[above] {13} (H);
    \draw (H) edge[geldstrom] node[above right] {2} (U);
    \draw (U) edge[geldstrom] node[above right] {6} (H);
    \draw (B) edge[geldstrom] node[below right] {10} (U);
    \draw (U) edge[geldstrom] node[below right] {7} (B);
    \draw (B) edge[geldstrom] node[below] {12} (A);
    \draw (A) edge[geldstrom] node[below] {19} (B);
    \draw (A) edge[geldstrom] node[above right] {18} (U);
    \draw (U) edge[geldstrom] node[above right] {8} (A);
    \draw (A) edge[geldstrom] node[right] {17} (S);
    \draw (S) edge[geldstrom] node[right] {14} (A);
    \draw (S) edge[geldstrom] node[below right] {15} (U);
    \draw (U) edge[geldstrom] node[below right] {5} (S);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[inner sep=6pt,pos=0.78]
    \draw (H) edge[bend right=80,bendstrom,looseness=1.7] node[below left] {4} (A);
    \draw (A) edge[bend left=80,bendstrom,looseness=1.7] node[below left] {20} (H);
    \draw (B) edge[bend left=80,bendstrom,looseness=1.7] node[above left] {11} (S);
    \draw (S) edge[bend right=80,bendstrom,looseness=1.7] node[above left] {16} (B);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```